# Cypress catch and validate a redirect

Tags: cypress, dynamic-testing

We're creating E2E tests in Cypress. One of our tests shows a list of banks to which you can be redirected to complete a payment. After clicking a specific bank with the following code:

```js
cy.get('.modal')
  .contains('Bunq')
  .click()
```

The following happens:

1. A request is sent to our back-end `http://localhost:4200/api/bunq` which responds with an `redirect url`
2. The browser is redirected to the redirect URL which is another domain: `https://example.com?_id=uniqueIdGeneratedAfterButtonClick`. *Please note that we can only generate this link after the user has clicked one of the options!*

Obviously we could mimmic the request that happens after the click with `cy.request` and check the response for validity. But I am curious if Cypress can confirm that the browser is indeed redirected to another domain (e.g. catching the error that is thrown).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just check what page it's on afterwards? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46839520/3001761

Comment: Redirection means just a different site in the current browser tab? If so, I guess you can check whatever there is on the site, including the url with `cy.url()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes there is, since it is another domain it fails to load `Refused to display 'https://api.pay.nl/xxxxxxx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`. Therefore calling `cy.url()` afterwards does not give me  the URL to which we are redirected in the end.

Comment: This is useful context to include *in the question*.